# htaccess rewrite rule to redirect .mp3 extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make a rewrite rule that will rewrite this:

```
example.com/audio.mp3
```

To this:

```
example.com/stats.php?file=audio.mp3
```

I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file.php?file=$1 [QSA]
```

This is working as long as I don't add a file extension to the URL. As soon as I do, I get a 404 not found page.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this above your other lines of code, I do believe it should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.mp3$ /stats.php?file=$1 [L]
```